# Small bootable flash drive for Mac

Tags: mac, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, formatting, usb-boot

I'd like to boot from a flash drive containing some disk management utilities, like disk partitioning on a mac (MacBook Pro).  All the instructions I've seen require an OSX installation disk with a >= 8GB flash drive.  I have a 2GB flash drive and no installation disk for OSX at the moment.  I'm looking for a compact solution to make this flash drive bootable so that I can do some drive management.

Comment: You're going to need OSX installation media, whether on optical media, or downloaded from the app store. There's no getting around that.

Comment: Boot a linux livecd image.  It will fit on 2GB.  You of course will have to make sure that you sue the GPT aware partition tools, or else you probably will trash everything.